# Understanding official blender documentation - reset button in an Addon example

Tags: python, documentation

I did the [Addon examples of the oficial documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_64_9/info_tutorial_addon.html) and there is something I don´t understand. In the section called "Bringing it all together" there is something about a reset button that appears below on the left. I don´t see it in my blender program. 
[image]

At first I thought it was something of the script code. But as you can see below, there isn´t anything in the Addon code related with a reset button.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Cursor Array",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy


class ObjectCursorArray(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Object Cursor Array"""
    bl_idname = "object.cursor_array"
    bl_label = "Cursor Array"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    total = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Steps", default=2, min=1, max=100)

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        cursor = scene.cursor_location
        obj = scene.objects.active

        for i in range(self.total):
            obj_new = obj.copy()
            scene.objects.link(obj_new)

            factor = i / self.total
            obj_new.location = (obj.location * factor) + (cursor * (1.0 - factor))

        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ObjectCursorArray.bl_idname)

# store keymaps here to access after registration
addon_keymaps = []


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectCursorArray)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)

    # handle the keymap
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Mode', space_type='EMPTY')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(ObjectCursorArray.bl_idname, 'SPACE', 'PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=True)
    kmi.properties.total = 4
    addon_keymaps.append(km)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectCursorArray)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)

    # handle the keymap
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    for km in addon_keymaps:
        wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.remove(km)
    # clear the list
    del addon_keymaps[:]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

How can I see this button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blender 2.64 there was indeed a "Reset" button. If you download blender 2.64 and do the same tutorial you will find the Reset button. Blender added this button automatically right under your operation panel.

In a later version the Reset button has been removed hence you don't see it anymore.